# Refer to a comment

Tags: support, comments

I need to refer to a previous comment in a question/answer/comment. How can I link to this comment?

Comment: Are you asking how to include a link in a comment?

Comment: @NathanOsman No.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click on the time displayed right next to the comment. [image]

Clicking on it will highlight the comment and the URL will give you the link to the comment.

[image]